# How can I use a third-party repo, which requires a conda environment, within my Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, conda, miniconda

I'm setting up a Django project on an Ubuntu 18.06 Digital Ocean droplet. I'm using python3-venv to create virtual environment in my project root, and have installed django and other dependencies within this.

I'm using a DRF class SplitTrackView(APIView): within which I want to call the separator.separate_to_file method from the spleeter project: https://github.com/deezer/spleeter

I've currently cloned the spleeter repo into my project folder, and installed miniconda in my home directory, but the second step in the spleeter setup instructions is:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spleeter
```

So here I'm creating a new virtual envorinment in conda to allow spleeter to run.

My questions are:

1. Is cloning the repo into my project root the best approach?
2. How do I handle dependency management when I have a virtual environment for my Django project, and a separate conda one to run spleeter?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to include all dependencies in one virtual env.